# Should I create QLineEdits in the constructor or in a method?

Tags: c++, qt, object, methods, constructor

I have a (hopefully) simple question:

I created a new class which has a form ( form.ui). In this form I want to build certain lineEdits. I want to do this by coding not by drag& drop. I can think of 2 different ways to do that:

1. in the constructor of the form.cpp I define the lineEdits, move them, give them a color,...
2. I do nothing in the constructor but opening form.ui. Then I run another method that defines the lineEdits, moves them, gives them a color,...

Which way is best to use ?

Thank you

itelly

Comment: Create layout, set it to your ui. Create `QLineEdit`. Move edit to layout. Done.

Comment: Personally, I like to do this kind of thing in the constructor. Others move it to a separate member function that is called in the constructor. I guess it depends on both personal preference and readability of the code. Not to forget it also depends on what flexibility you want in changing all the properties.

Comment: I want to do it by coding, not with a layout.

Comment: Layout is your basis for any widget, QLineEdit included

Comment: This is mostly opinion based. Of course if you have a lot of widgets, creating them all in the constructor (or even in the same function) will leave you with a ridiculously long constructor, which will be difficult to traverse. So initializing your widgets in separate functions might not be a bad idea. It all depends on you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think - how to do (from constructor or by method) it does not matter and completly depends on your goals.

Here is an example code for your task:

**Using some ui `QWidget` class:**

```
QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(this);
QLineEdit *someEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
lay->addWidget(someEdit);
```

**Using some ui `QMainWindow` class:**

```
QVBoxLayout *lay = new QVBoxLayout(ui->centralWidget);
QLineEdit *someEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
lay->addWidget(someEdit);
```